# PUT request via postman works, but via python requests not

Tags: python, api, python-requests, postman, put

When I send PUT request via postman everything is ok, but when I copy code from postman to python I get this:

```
{"code": 50035, "errors": {"_errors": [{"code": "CONTENT_TYPE_INVALID", "message": "Expected \"Content-Type\" header to be one of {'application/json'}."}]}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}
```

the code:

```
url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/860859559908474900/premium/subscriptions"

payload={'user_premium_guild_subscription_slot_ids': '853228009795223572'}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'authorization': 'here token',
  'Cookie': '__dcfduid=c5cbabf10a8344558c8c4b90a6e306e2'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

if I add 'content-type' : 'application/json' to headers, I get this:

`{"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}`

Comment: You should include the correct content-type, and *then* work out what causes the next error (400).

Comment: Content-type application-Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `json=` instead of `data=` or add the `Content-Type` header with value `application/json` as the server tells you.

Also check the `Authorization` header, mostly there's a prefix which mentions what auth to use e.g.:

```
Authorization: Basic base64-encoded(user:pass)
Authorization: Bearer token
Authorization: Token token
```

and make sure the `files` parameter is actually allowed to be empty by the API and if not, try removing it.

Then there's `__dcfduid` cookie you provide. Some cookies tend to be dynamic as in the value changes between requests. Try then establishing the session and do the login part within it:

```py
import requests as r
ses = r.Session()
resp = ses.post(<login to the API>)
print(resp.text)
ses.put(
    url="https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/860859559908474900/premium/subscriptions",
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'here token',
        # cookies are in the ses object
    },
    json={
        'user_premium_guild_subscription_slot_ids': '853228009795223572'
    },
    # if required
    files=[...]
)
```

Comment: if i use json= instead of data= i get this error:

https://pastebin.com/raw/gnb6zHH0

(its to long to paste it here)

and if i add 'content-type' : 'application/json' to headers, i get this:

```{"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}```

but if i use json= and add 'content-type' : 'application/json' i get also this error
https://pastebin.com/raw/gnb6zHH0

Comment: @1bura So you've moved one step closer - the long message is getting closer to the successful response. Judging by what it says (`SET_TYPE_ALREADY_CONTAINS_VALUE`) whatever data you're passing apparently are already configured. Try to remove them manually, then call the API.

Comment: it writes SET_TYPE_ALREADY_CONTAINS_VALUE but it doesnt true, checkout this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpyyJH1mc9M    (yeah i know that its authorization token there, i just dont need it, its my test token and u can take it)